# Building Mean Scale in R

Tags: r, scale

I'm trying to analyze a longitudinal questionnaire that consists of 5 questions. Let's say the participants were to answer this questionnaire 4 times.

Now, I want to build a scale that is called task performance. This scale is build by the mean of question 1, 2 and 5.

I need this mean for each of the 5 measurement points. Is there an easier way to compute these means than I did in the example below?

```
df$performance_T1 <- with(df, rowMeans(cbind(Task1T1,Task2T1,Task5T1), na.rm = TRUE))
df$performance_T2 <- with(df, rowMeans(cbind(Task1T2,Task2T2,Task5T2), na.rm = TRUE))
df$performance_T3 <- with(df, rowMeans(cbind(Task1T3,Task2T3,Task5T3), na.rm = TRUE))
df$performance_T4 <- with(df, rowMeans(cbind(Task1T4,Task2T4,Task5T4), na.rm = TRUE))
```

My data frame would look like this in this example:

```
df = data.frame(Task1T1 <- c(1:5),
            Task2T1 <- c(1:5),
            Task3T1 <- c(1:5),
            Task4T1 <- c(1:5),
            Task5T1 <- c(1:5),
            Task1T2 <- c(1:5),
            Task2T2 <- c(1:5),
            Task3T2 <- c(1:5),
            Task4T2 <- c(1:5),
            Task5T2 <- c(1:5),
            Task1T3 <- c(1:5),
            Task2T3 <- c(1:5),
            Task3T3 <- c(1:5),
            Task4T3 <- c(1:5),
            Task5T3 <- c(1:5),
            Task1T4 <- c(1:5),
            Task2T4 <- c(1:5),
            Task3T4 <- c(1:5),
            Task4T4 <- c(1:5),
            Task5T4 <- c(1:5))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that in your data set:

1. Each row is a person
2. Each "task" and "measurement" is in a column.

We can use the `tidyverse`, along with the principles of [tidy data](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf), to restructure the data.

In the below example, I've added an explicit `person_id` for clarity.

```
library(tidyverse)

df = structure(list(Task1T1 = 1:5, Task2T1 = 1:5, Task3T1 = 1:5, Task4T1 = 1:5, 
                    Task5T1 = 1:5, Task1T2 = 1:5, Task2T2 = 1:5, Task3T2 = 1:5, 
                    Task4T2 = 1:5, Task5T2 = 1:5, Task1T3 = 1:5, Task2T3 = 1:5, 
                    Task3T3 = 1:5, Task4T3 = 1:5, Task5T3 = 1:5, Task1T4 = 1:5, 
                    Task2T4 = 1:5, Task3T4 = 1:5, Task4T4 = 1:5, Task5T4 = 1:5), 
               .Names = c("Task1T1", "Task2T1", "Task3T1", "Task4T1", "Task5T1", 
                          "Task1T2", "Task2T2", "Task3T2", "Task4T2", "Task5T2", 
                          "Task1T3", "Task2T3", "Task3T3", "Task4T3", "Task5T3", 
                          "Task1T4", "Task2T4", "Task3T4", "Task4T4", "Task5T4"), 
               row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

df %>% 
    mutate(person_id = row_number()) %>%
    gather(task, score, -person_id) %>%
    separate(task, into = c("Task", "Measurement"), sep = "T(?=\\d)") %>%
    group_by(Task, person_id) %>%
    summarise(Performance = mean(score, na.rm = T)) ->
    perf

head(perf)
#> Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
#> Groups: Task [2]
#> 
#>    Task person_id Performance
#>   <chr>     <int>       <dbl>
#> 1 Task1         1           1
#> 2 Task1         2           2
#> 3 Task1         3           3
#> 4 Task1         4           4
#> 5 Task1         5           5
#> 6 Task2         1           1
```

If you want the data back in the format of one person in a row, and the task average in columns, you can swing it back out.

```
perf %>%
    spread(Task, Performance, fill = 0)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 6
#>   person_id Task1 Task2 Task3 Task4 Task5
#> *     <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1         1     1     1     1     1     1
#> 2         2     2     2     2     2     2
#> 3         3     3     3     3     3     3
#> 4         4     4     4     4     4     4
#> 5         5     5     5     5     5     5
```